# Javascript Storing DOM HTML element reference

Tags: javascript

I am working in Javascript code where I frequently use .querySelector() method for some DOM manipulation,

Ex:

```
Fn1(){
    myview.querySelector('.tab1').classList.add('active');
    myview.querySelector('.tab2').classList.remove('active');
}

Fn2(){
    var mylist = "<div>somelist</div>";
    myview.querySelector('.tab1').appendChild(mylist);
}

Fn3(){
    var tab1 =  myview.querySelector('.tab1')
    tab1.querySelector('.xyz').addEventListener('click', search.bind(null, myview));     
}
```

**`myview.querySelector('.tab1')`** is used in many times, so I thinking to store in my Class public variable like

```
var tab1 = myview.querySelector('.tab1');
```

So any function can use it any time. Here my doubt is **"Any drawback or Performance issue will come if I store my DOM Object reference in Javscript variable?"**

Comment: `appenChild` Spelling matters in programming. Also, you can't `appendChild` with text, though you can append elements. But the general idea seems fine, store references to as many elements as you want

Comment: if anything it ought to be _more_ efficient, not less, because you reduce the amount of searching in the DOM

Comment: DOM search and DOM manipulations are expensive, so if you want to reuse an element multiple times, storing it in a variable (which of course will allocate memory) is the way to go.

Comment: Better to provide `Id` and use `document.getElementById('Id')` Instead of class

Comment: @manikantgautam There's absolutely nothing wrong with using classes instead of `id`s. Using `querySelector` for classes is just fine

Comment: @manikantgautam: we can't run by getElementById inside another DOM view, Ex: mydiv.querySelctor will work but myDiv.getElementById will give error

Comment: @manikantgautam yes that's more efficient, but it's assuming you only want to select a single element whose ID is known. And selecting that element once and storing in a variable will still (when it needs to be accessed multiple times) be more efficient than repeating calls to getElementById - that was the actual question being asked, it was not about which DOM method to use. We have to assume that the use of classes is useful and/or necessary in the given scenario.